# why the div tag not fit to the top in the body?

Tags: html, css

My html code is

```
 <html>
 <body id="body">
 <div id="content">
 <div id="head1">
 <h3 id="cpsir">CPSIR-CM</h3>
 </div>
 </div>
 </html>
```

Css code is

```
#body{
background:#0F657D;
}
#content{ 
width:1000px;
height:740px; 
background:#E2E2E2; 
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
}
#head1{
width:auto; 
height:60px; 
background:#626262; 
margin-top:-10px;    
}
#cpsir{
font-family:Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:24px; 
color:#F4F4F4; 
padding-top:10px;
```

}

I'm trying to fit the `head` div tag to the top of the body. But which is not fit perfectly. So, I'm used the negative px for it., but which result is differ to the different browser. For example, In the torch browser `margin-top:-10px` gives what i expect , which is change into the Internet Explorer. What can i do?

Comment: You should remove the margin from the `body` and not use the negative              margin

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uwLL0sr7/1/ ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp

Comment: You did not end your body, you should always end tags. This is the best for compatibility with all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with:

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

And then you shouldn't need the negative margin on `#head1`

Answer (score 1):

A starter tip i got once when optimizing for different browsers:

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

that way all elements are rendered the same in every browser, since IE have one way of putting small margins here and there, as do Firefox, Chrome, etc.

You can just put margins on elements afterwards